# Mocking simple internal function using Jest for use in rendered React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a simple React application with the following `App.js`, `App.test.js`, and `utils.js` files:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { randomNameGenerator } from './utils.js';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {randomNameGenerator()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import App from './App';

it('allows Jest method mocking', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  expect(getByText("Craig")).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

**utils.js**

```
export function randomNameGenerator() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1) == 1 ? 'Steve' : 'Bill';
}
```

This is a simple example, but what I'm *trying to accomplish* is a Jest mock of the `randomNameGenerator()` function to only return `"Craig"` for that **specific Jest test**.

I've followed a wide variety of tutorials/guides, but can't find anything that works - the closest (by "feel") that I've gotten was this (in `App.test.js`), which had no effect:

```
jest.doMock('./utils', () => {
  const originalUtils = jest.requireActual('./utils');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalUtils,
    randomNameGenerator: jest.fn(() => {
      console.log('## Returning mocked typing duration!');
      return 'Craig';
    }),
  };
})
```

**The way it fails** is expected:

```
Unable to find an element with the text: Craig. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          Steve
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

       6 | it('allows Jest method mocking', () => {
       7 |   const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    >  8 |   expect(getByText("Craig")).toBeInTheDocument()
         |          ^
       9 | });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mock the module by calling `jest.mock`, and then import it, then inside your tests you call `mockImplementation` to setup the right return value.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import App from './App';

import { randomNameGenerator } from "./utils";

jest.mock('./utils.js', () => ({ 
  randomNameGenerator: jest.fn()
}));

describe('test', () => {
  it('allows Jest method mocking 1', () => {
    randomNameGenerator.mockImplementation(() => "Craig");
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    expect(getByText("Craig")).toBeInTheDocument()
  });

  it('allows Jest method mocking 2', () => {
    randomNameGenerator.mockImplementation(() => "Not Craig");
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    expect(getByText("Not Craig")).toBeInTheDocument()
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to mostly work, with one caveat. It requires **every** test method to provide a mock implementation of the `randomNameGenerator` method - there's no 'default' which falls back to the original implementation in the case where a mock has not been defined. I tried a few attempts at setting this up in the `jest.mock()` using `requireActual` but encountered scope access issues (`not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables`)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately looks like there isn't any official way of doing this, you may wanna check this on github: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2649